# Maturing US Treasury Securities: value from TreasuryDirect vs New York Fed SOMA Holdings

Tags: federal-reserve, securities, treasuries

## TreasuryDirect

If I query TreasuryDirect for securities that are maturing in Aug 2022:

```
$result = Invoke-RestMethod ('http://www.treasurydirect.gov/TA_WS/securities/search?maturityDate={0},{1}&format=json' -f '2022-08-01', '2022-08-31')
```

And show the results:

```
$result | Sort-Object issueDate | Format-Table -Property cusip, securityType, securityTerm, auctionDate, issueDate, maturityDate, somaAccepted
```

I get the following:

[image]

Getting the total value:

```
'{0:C0}' -f ($result | Measure-Object -Property somaAccepted -Sum).Sum
```

returns:

```
$116,558,288,800
```

## SOMA Holdings

If I query the New York Fed for the treasury security SOMA holdings as of July 27th 2022:

```
$result_tsy = Invoke-RestMethod ('https://markets.newyorkfed.org/api/soma/tsy/get/all/asof/{0}.json' -f '2022-07-27')
```

And show the items with a maturity date in Aug:

```
$result_tsy.soma.holdings | Where-Object maturityDate -GE '2022-08-01' | Where-Object maturityDate -LE '2022-08-31' | Format-Table *
```

I get the following:

[image]

If I calculate the total parValue:

```
'{0:C0}' -f ($result_tsy.soma.holdings | Where-Object maturityDate -GE '2022-08-01' | Where-Object maturityDate -LE '2022-08-31' | Measure-Object -Property parValue -Sum).Sum
```

I get:

```
$194,344,004,700
```

## Question

Comparing the two values:

```
TreasuryDirect:     $116,558,288,800
SOMA Holdings USTS: $194,344,004,700
```

I'm guessing that the USTS SOMA Holdings value is the authoritative answer as far as knowing how much is maturing in Aug.

Why is the TreasuryDirect value lower?

## PowerShell

All of the commands above can be run at a PowerShell prompt on Windows (or Mac and Linux if you have it installed there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes the SOMA value is the one to use. The Treasury Direct somaAccepted value is the amount the SOMA took when the auction of that treasury occurred but does not reflect any purchases the FED may have made from their dealers post issuance. For example. cusip 912828TJ9 were 10yr UST issued back in 2012. FED didnt take any at auction but purchased a bunch since then (without looking it up Id guess during bazooka QE in early 2020).